# Valid URL for an FTP site with username containing @

Tags: url, ftp, autohotkey

I want to create a valid URL to send to Windows File Explorer (or other file managers like TotalCommander) using the format:

```
ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.ext/folder/
```

In Explorer, it works with very straight username and password. But I receive errors (or Explorer just display the My Document instead of the FTP site) when password contains certain special characters. I played with URI encoding to encode the password with some success but not 100% reliable.

Can someone help me finding the correct requirements for a valid FTP URL including username and password? Thanks.

Here is a sample of the code using AutoHotkey "Run" command (on Windows 7 64-bit environment):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force

strFTPUrl := "ftp://www.jeanlalonde.ca"

strLoginName := "username@jeanlalonde.ca"
strPassword := "********"

StringReplace, strFTPUrl, strFTPUrl, % "ftp://", % "ftp://" . strLoginName . ":" . UriEncode(strPassword) . "@"

; Before: ftp://ftp.jeanlalonde.ca
; After: ftp://testaccount@jeanlalonde.ca:********@ftp.jeanlalonde.ca
MsgBox, %strFTPUrl%

Run, Explorer "%strFTPUrl%"

return


;------------------------------------------------------------
UriEncode(str)
; from GoogleTranslate by Mikhail Kuropyatnikov
; http://www.autohotkey.net/~sumon/GoogleTranslate.ahk
;------------------------------------------------------------
{ 
   b_Format := A_FormatInteger 
   data := "" 
   SetFormat,Integer,H 
   SizeInBytes := StrPutVar(str,var,"utf-8")
   Loop, %SizeInBytes%
   {
   ch := NumGet(var,A_Index-1,"UChar")
   If (ch=0)
      Break
   if ((ch>0x7f) || (ch<0x30) || (ch=0x3d))
      s .= "%" . ((StrLen(c:=SubStr(ch,3))<2) ? "0" . c : c)
   Else
      s .= Chr(ch)
   }   
   SetFormat,Integer,%b_format% 
   return s 
} 
;------------------------------------------------------------


;------------------------------------------------------------
StrPutVar(string, ByRef var, encoding)
;------------------------------------------------------------
{
    ; Ensure capacity.
    SizeInBytes := VarSetCapacity( var, StrPut(string, encoding)
        ; StrPut returns char count, but VarSetCapacity needs bytes.
        * ((encoding="utf-16"||encoding="cp1200") ? 2 : 1) )
    ; Copy or convert the string.
    StrPut(string, &var, encoding)
   Return SizeInBytes 
}
;------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I edited my question, adding sample code. One of the issue I see is that there is an ampersand (@) in the username (my hosting provider forces this). So, there are two ampersands in the URL: one in the username and the other before the ftp site address. Should the first one be encode or escaped in some way?

Comment: Thanks for re-editing the question, Martin. It made it mode to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are special characters (`@` being one) in the username too (not only in the password), you have to URL-encode the username too, the same way you URL-encode the password.

That means you have to apply the `UriEncode` to `strLoginName`, the same way you apply it to `strPassword`.

And you need to update the `UriEncode` to encode the `@`, as it does not.

The code for `@` is `0x40`.

```
if ((ch>0x7f) || (ch<0x30) || (ch=0x3d) || (ch=0x40))
```

(Though you can compare to `@` literally too: `ch="@"`).

Comment: It is exactly what was missing. Thanks for the answer, Martin!